# Find files in a dircetory with special character in its name

Tags: python, regex

I tried to find files in a directory whose name include `-`, i.e. `/0.12345/Name-001-011`. Part of the code do it is like this

```
mypath = '.'
pattern = '\d\.\d*/Name*/NameofFile'
fileList = []

for directory, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mypath):
   for name in filenames:

     if re.search(pattern,os.path.join(directory,name)):
         fileList.append(os.path.join(directory,name))
```

but unfortunately it does not find the file, and as I realised the problem stems from having `-` in the path.

Comment: @9769953 Since in the directory, there may be some other folder contains `-`, I could not

Comment: Try with raw strings: `r'\d\.\d*/Name*/NameofFile'`

Comment: @9769953 The dir name contains dash.

Comment: @Silveris it does not work

Comment: @9769953 Thanks, now it works

Comment: @Pejvak Yeah just realized it won't work because with raw strings \ is processed as a regular character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a missing dot in the regex pattern after `Name`. The correct pattern is below:

```
/\d\.\d*/Name.*/NameofFile
```

As pointed out in the comments, by writing `Name*` you tell the engine to match 0 or more repetitions of the character `e`. Instead what you want presumably is to match anything after `Name` which is achieved by `.*` where dot stands for any character except newline.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that our desired output would be `Name-001-011`, which this simple expression would capture that:

```
/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/(.+)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/01TVbZ/1/)

If we might want to add `Name` as a boundary and capture the digits, we can try:

```
/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/Name-(.+)
```

or:

```
/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/(Name-.+)
```

or:

```
/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/(Name-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/NmdAqf/1/)